# NA values in community matrix makes Hmsc object hard to interpret

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis

For an analyis of the effect of precipitation onto a given species trait, I am trying to interpret an hmsc model I have created. To do so, I have log transformed my community matrix `data_comm` to have normally distributed data, but had to remove all zeroes beforehand to obtain `YData_abu` (columns are species names, rows are locations)

```
# to log transform the original data, I remove all zeros and obtain an abundance matrix
YData_abu<-data_comm
YData_abu[YData_abu==0]<-NA
YData_abu<-log(YData_abu)

head (YData_abu)
>      VTX00392 VTX00040 VTX00383 VTX00310 VTX00242 VTX00264 VTX00309 VTX00009 VTX00272 VTX00375 VTX00008 VTX00017 VTX00279 VTX00307 VTX00278
> 1       NA 1.945910       NA 2.944439       NA        0 2.302585       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
> 2       NA 1.386294       NA 2.708050       NA       NA 1.609438       NA       NA 2.079442       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
> 3      NA 0.000000  1.94591 8.160232       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA 2.197225
```

From that I have fitted an Hmsc model object called `m`. To visualize the effect of precipitation, I created a gradient (trait vs. precipitation) and a matrix of predicted values `predY` which naturally contains a lot of NaNs.

```
Gradient = constructGradient(m,focalVariable = "precipitation",non.focalVariables = 2)
predY = predict(m,
                XData = Gradient$XDataNew, 
            studyDesign = Gradient$studyDesignNew,
                ranLevels = Gradient$rLNew,
                expected = TRUE)

head(predY)

> VTX00392  VTX00040 VTX00383 VTX00310    VTX00242  VTX00264 VTX00309 VTX00009 VTX00272  VTX00375 VTX00008 VTX00017 VTX00279 VTX00307 VTX00278
> 1       NaN 2.0241094 2.177248 3.500090  0.71732051 0.9008549 1.673947      NaN      NaN 0.8123212      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN 2.437930
> 2       NaN 1.9504484 2.192804 3.620343  0.67901260 0.9010499 1.767086      NaN      NaN 0.8152907      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN 2.415085
> 3       NaN 1.8767873 2.208359 3.740596  0.64070468 0.9012449 1.860225      NaN      NaN 0.8182603      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN 2.392240
```

However, because of the missing values, it seems like I cannot visualize the gradient. Is there any other way to visually interprete the connection between a chosen species trait and environmental factor?

````
plotGradient(m_fitted, 
             Gradient,
             predY =predY,
             measure="T",
             index = 2,
             yshow = range(predY,na.rm=T))

> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In min(lo, yshow, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> 2: In max(hi, yshow, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```
````

Comment: Eliminating zeroes seems drastic. How about using log(value + 0.5)?